# Debugging Codeception tests with Xdebug

Tags: php, testing, xdebug, codeception

I wrote some API tests with Codeception's ApiGuy. Now I want to set breakpoints in my PhpStorm 7 for tests debugging, but have no idea how to start debug session after `$ vendor/bin/codecept run`. I know about `--debug` option, but it's not exactly what I want.

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vote for codeception support in phpStorm https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16350

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Seems that *Codeception* only comes with a command line tool, which cannot be debugged. I finally ended up writing my own PHP runner, which is basically a lite copy of the `codeception` command executable.

Actually all you would have to do in Linux is to remove the shebang from the `codeception` tool to run it as a PHP script. But since commands other then `codeception run` are much less likely to be a subject of debugging, I've prepared a separate PHP script. It contains only the `run` option:

```
<?php
/**
 * Codeception PHP script runner
 */

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/codeception/codeception/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$app = new Application('Codeception', Codeception\Codecept::VERSION);
$app->add(new Codeception\Command\Run('run'));

$app->run();
```

After you get this done you can set up your debugging script like any other in *PHPStorm*. So go to the `Select Run/Debug Configuration` > `Edit Configurations...`:

[image: Edit Configurations...]

Now `Add New Configuration (Alt + Insert)` > `PHP Script`. Then name the run configuration and select the file you created above. Remember to add the `run` argument:

[image]

And that's it. Now you can run your tests from within the IDE and debug them as ordinary scripts.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, works like a charm! I've specified also custom working directory to my project root to avoid config exception.

Comment: This works. For anyone else troubleshooting, try putting the `run.php` file you create in the same directory as your `codeception.yml`. that got it working for me.

Comment: You are a freaking genius! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 21):

I use the codecept.phar file and I find this one does work.
just type this command in the console and then run the codeception tests:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=session_name remote_host=localhost profiler_enable=1"
```

Comment: It is if you use a batch script shortcut

Comment: This will also work when using a remote server to run the codeception. You just have to specify a different remote_host in that export line.

Comment: In some cases (running a script on one machine, debugging remotely), it may be useful to set export XDEBUG_CONFIG="autostart=on". Every script you invoke will start the debugger with the settings already populated in php/cli/php.ini

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to use

```
php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_autostart=On -dxdebug.idekey=YOUR_KEY -dxdebug.remote_host=YOUR_IP ../vendor/bin/codecept run
```

Comment: Works great. Just place it into "Interpreter options" in the configuration dialog (options part only, without "php " and "../vendor/bin/codecept run").

Answer (score 2):

Alias could be used

```
alias xon="export XDEBUG_CONFIG=\"profiler_enable=1\""
alias xoff="export XDEBUG_CONFIG=\"profiler_enable=0\""
```

And then we could use `xon` in console to start debug and `xoff` to finish.

http://theaveragedev.com/debug-cli-scripts-with-phpstorm

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to configure PhpStorm, as above, but set `bin/cept` for **File**, `run` for **Arguments**, and the root of your project as **Custom Working Directory**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually need an extra script to debug Codeception at least in PHPStorm. I don't think you would in other IDEs either. You can set codecept.phar as the "File" in your configuration shown in Maciej Sz's answer  and run it as you would any other command line script from PHPStorm, Eclipse, etc.

In PHPStorm you create a new PHP Script debug configuration pointing at codecept.phar as the "File". Set the arguments to be a basic run configuration (e.g. run acceptance --group mygroup --env myenv), but tell it to "Show this page" every time you want to debug. You can then change which test/group/environment you are running each time to run your test with breakpoints.

When you click the debug button from the pop-up the acceptance test starts in the debugger console.

The initial run that hits a break-point will be in the validation phase where Codeception attempts to ensure the code will run before running it. The second run will be when the test is actually using Selenium or whatever you have configured. This will allow you to see what is in memory, step over things in a controlled manner, etc.